# Changing Check boxes positions when scrolling UITableList

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have inserted one Button on my tableList for check and unchecked the products, For this I have used below code but when I scroll my tableList already checked boxes are un-checking and their positions also changing

How can I solve this problem?

my code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return mainArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[MaintableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }

    model1 = mainArray[indexPath.row];


    newBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(250,5,30,30)];
    [newBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(urSelctor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIImage *btnImage;
    if(model1.ischeck){
        btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    }else{
        btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
    }
    [newBtn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell addSubview:newBtn];

    return cell;
}

-(void)urSelctor :(UIButton*)sender{

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:MaintableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [MaintableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    NSInteger variable = indexPath1.row;
    model1 = mainArray[variable];

    if (model1.ischeck){
        model1.ischeck = NO;
        [mainArray replaceObjectAtIndex:variable withObject:model1];
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{
        model1.ischeck = YES;
        [mainArray replaceObjectAtIndex:variable withObject:model1];
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [MaintableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

### modelObject:-

```
@interface ModelObject1 : NSObject{
    BOOL  ischeck;
}

@property(nonatomic) BOOL ischeck;

@end
```

Comment: Cells are reused, so you will add multiple buttons to your cells as you scroll.  You should create a subclass of UITableViewCell and add the button in `- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
              reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`.  Also since you are modifying the object that is in the array, there is no need to replace it with itself using `replaceObjectAtIndex`

Comment: yes i added but no use same result i am getting

Comment: remove this line [newBtn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; and paste it in both if and else condition..sometime scrolling change the value..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
}
```

Edit `reuseIdentifier is nil` and try.

Comment: bool model1  what is this ?

Comment: bool model1  is  bool variable just use.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to define a custom tableview cell.

If you want to make just a simple change to your code remove the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` call and just create new cells. It isn't the best idea, but it will get your code working.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one Custom cell of type UITableViewCell. It will solve your problem. As you are adding new button object every time in cellForRow. It will also consume more memory. Never addSubview in cellForRow if it's not too much required.

See I have done in this demo:

https://sendspace.com/file/vjzu74

Comment: @krish nope it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Code:

```
-(void)btnPressed :(id)sender
{
    CGPoint point=[sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *index= [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
    [category manageCell:index.row];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *const cellIdentifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier ];
    }
    UIButton *checkBtn=[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    [checkBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    if([category.indexArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]])
    {

        [checkBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [checkBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    return cell;
}


-(void)manageCell:(NSInteger)index
{
    if(![_indexArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index]])
    {
        [_indexArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index]];
    }
    else
    {
        [_indexArray removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index]];

    }
       NSLog(@"%@",_indexArray);
}
```