# How to implement check boxes functionality on UITableView in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, checkbox

In my ios app I have added on one button in `UITableViewCell` which is for check and un-check the TableViewCell products. For this I wrote below code but according to my code by default all are checked and when I scroll check boxes are un-checking

### my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    checkBoxesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i = 0; i <15; i++){

        [checkBoxesArray addObject:@""];
    }
}

//TableList Delegate Methods:

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return checkBoxesArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HistoryCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[MaintableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }

    model1 = mainArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = model1.Name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = model1.MasterId;

    bool variable = checkBoxesArray[indexPath.row];

    newBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(250,5,30,30)];
    [newBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(urSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIImage *btnImage;
    if(variable == YES){
        NSLog(@"1");
        btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"2");
        btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
    }
    [newBtn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell addSubview:newBtn];

    return cell;
}



-(void)urSelector :(UIButton*)sender{

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:MaintableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [MaintableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    NSInteger variable = indexPath1.row;

    bool variablePosition = checkBoxesArray[variable];

    if (variablePosition == YES){

        variablePosition= NO;
        [checkBoxesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:variable withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",variablePosition]];
    }
    else{
        variablePosition = YES;
        [checkBoxesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:variable withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",variablePosition]];
    }

    [MaintableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Comment: my qus is diff if know solution please provide

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605575/using-checkboxes-in-uitableviewcell-when-the-checkbox-and-the-cell-behaviour-m

Comment: i want to implement my logic what is mistack?

Comment: try in the place `newBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];` into `UIButton *newBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

Comment: and change this `[cell addSubview:newBtn];` into `[cell.conetntView  addSubview:newBtn];`

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: can you updated the quetion once

Answer (score 1):

1) Add one `key` to your model array. Like `isSelected` and set it's value to `NO`.

2) Now when you select any cell at that time set the value of that key to `YES`.

3) In `cellForRow`, access that key which we have added and check it's value. If it's YES then set Check Image else Uncheck image.

4) Don't maintain two array so remove your `checkboxarray`. It will create confusion for you.

Comment: hi @Bhadresh Mulsaniya

Comment: @Krish Hi, How can I help you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261018/changing-check-boxes-positions-when-scrolling-uitablelist

Comment: please see this link

Comment: @Krish okay no problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116951/discussion-between-krish-and-bhadresh-mulsaniya).

Comment: @Krish Please check demo which I have created for you: https://www.sendspace.com/file/vjzu74

Comment: what is this is this related my question?

Comment: is it wrong process i mean i am talking about below  question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261018/changing-check-boxes-positions-when-scrolling-uitablelist

Comment: i think using Nsobject class is good for integrating webservices,What is ur openion?

Comment: Yes it's good. You have done right thing. But why you are using checkbox array.

Comment: Why you are not using model1.isCheck in cellForRow method?

Comment: please see below questiuon

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261018/changing-check-boxes-positions-when-scrolling-uitablelist

Comment: please suggest me there it self and that question also i posted

Answer (score 0):

First Please replace your line of code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
bool variable = checkBoxesArray[indexPath.row];
```

with

```
bool variable = [checkBoxesArray[indexPath.row] length] > 0;
```

Because in checkBoxesArray , there are NSString type objects. and you are storing them into a bool variable . It always returns a true value to your 'variable'. So first of all you need to have a proper condition for 'check' and 'uncheck' thing. I am assuming that you want all boxes unchecked for the first time. So I put blank string for uncheck button and some value string for check button.
Again you need to replace your code in urSelctor method

```
bool variablePosition = checkBoxesArray[variable];

if (variablePosition == YES){

    variablePosition= NO;
    [checkBoxesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:variable withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",variablePosition]];
}
```

with

```
bool variablePosition = [checkBoxesArray[variable] length] > 0;

if (variablePosition == YES){

    variablePosition= NO;
    [checkBoxesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:variable withObject:@""];
}
```

hope these things will help you.

Happy coding... :) :) :)